# python setup.py install strips out __init__.py

Tags: python, setup.py

Maybe it's something stupid I am doing or maybe I need to do something in `setup.py` or maybe it's a bug.

Python 2.6
Django 1.6

This is a reusable django app with multiple sub apps.  What makes it django related is the error.  When I try enable the sub apps django cannot find them.  The reason it cannot find them is because setup.py strips out the `__init__.py` during install.  When I manually add it back in at the install location it's ok.

The app folder and relevant file arrangement is as follows.

```
someapp
 django
  apps
   subapp1
   subapp2
   subapp3
   __init__.py
 setup.py
```

After `python setup.py install` the `__init__.py` shown above is missing from the install location and if that file is missing django cannot find subapp1, subapp2, subapp3 when I try add them to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

When I try add `someapp.django.apps.subapp1` django says

> No module named apps.subapp1

When I add the `__init__.py in`apps` folder in the install location that error goes away.

All other folders have `__init__.py` after running setup.py except `apps`.

I tried changing the `apps` directory name thinking maybe that's a reserved word but it didn't change anything.  I also tried adding something to the `__init__.py` file thinking maybe it can't be empty but didn't help.  Also tried adding an empty `models.py` file thinking there needed to be more there but still no dice.

My setup.py file is just standard boilerplate.  Maybe there is something I need to add.  I tried using distutils instead of setuptools but that didn't make a difference.

```
#setup.py

import os
from setuptools import setup

def read(fname):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()


setup(
    name = "appname",
    version = "0.0.1",
    author = "blah inc",
    author_email = "blah@blah.com",
    description = ("some description"),
    license = "MPL",
    keywords = "some keywords",
    url = "http://someurl.org",
    packages=[     
        'someapp',
        'someapp.api',
        'someapp.django',
        'someapp.django.apps.subapp1',
        'someapp.django.apps.subapp2',
        'someapp.django.apps.subapp3',
        'someapp.eventsocket',
        'someapp.interface',
    ],
   etc.
   etc.
   .
   .
)
```

Comment: Do you have a `MANIFEST.in` file in your project?

Comment: no `MANIFEST.in` file but that gave me an important clue.  If it's not included it is generated from the package_data.  However adding it to package_data still didn't work.  What worked was adding `someapp.django.apps` to `packages`.  Seems kind of odd to have to do that since adding it as a django app doesn't add the subapps so it doesn't serve any purpose other than to force setup.py to include the file in there.

Comment: You need to list every package in that list. `setuptools` includes a function to find packages for you though: http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#using-find-packages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed out the `someapp.django.apps` package; you must list *all* packages in that list.

You can make the task easier by using [`setuptools.find_packages()`](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#using-find-packages):

```
setup(
    # ...
    packages=find_packages(),

    # ...
)
```

Comment: Yes I see that now.  I also read about packages=find_packages().  That seemed too easy and I thought there was a catch or maybe it wouldn't work for all situations.  I've been using Django for awhile but total newbie to setup.py...obviously.